# Echo php var before the </head> (closing head) tag in order to retrieve it with java script

Tags: javascript

I have a php variable called **$myVar = "6542";**

Where can I echo it before the `</head>` tag of my site (and not trigger any html issues) in order to be able to pick the value up with javascript?

Ty

Comment: Anywhere inside a `head` tag? `<script>myVar = "<? echo htmlspecialchars($myVar); ?>";</script>`

Comment: Will this var be picked up by any externl js scripts?

Comment: yes, if you add it before including the js file

Comment: as long as it's echo'd into the page before your other scripts that need access to it.

Comment: @webmasters It's global--it'll be readable by anything that tries to access it after it's been declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw it above your  tag somewhere. Simple.

```
<script type="text/javascript>var myvar = '<?=htmlspecialchars($myVar);?>';</script>
```

It can be put anywhere on the page, not necessarily needing to be above

Comment: Adding a `htmlspecialchars()` would be nice just in case

Comment: @Pekka `json_encode` is more ideal for javascript escaping, it also encodes `</script>` as `"<\/script>"` so it wouldn't break the tag even

Comment: done, good suggestion (since if the string had any ' in it, it wouldn't be output correctly).

Comment: Hmm, ty very much, when I paste it in my source code I get an error. I use dreamweaver as a coding application and it says there is an error.. but it does not tell me what error.

Comment: I did it like this: <script type="text/javascript">var id = '6581';</script>

Answer (score 0):

Just about anywhere (the HEAD contents is the best place), provided that you wrap it up with a `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
  var myVar = "6542";
</script>
```